# AVFramework session issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

When i try to capture video by using AVFramework i receive an exception -11803, which says that the session is not started, the first time when i init session it works fine, but after when controller changes and then again return to the same controller it throws an exception, but in same session image capture works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved,the issue was that the session object was not deallocated properly.